# Expression reference to expression reference

Tags: angularjs

What's to best way to handle expression to expression?
I know I can add a lot of code to solve this, but wondering whether there is an easy solution in AngularJs API.

```
<h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1> <!-- works fine, shows 'Jim' -->
<h1>Hello {{yourTest}}!</h1> <!-- will show {{test}}, but I want 'Jack' -->

$scope.yourName = "Jim";
$scope.test = "Jack";
$scope.yourTest = "{{test}}";  //This must be a string in my case.
```

Comment: not sure what are you trying to do if you replace {{yourTest}} with {{test}} you get what you need...

Comment: @LiadLivnat Thanks, but above is just to demonstrate my case. In my situation the yourTest is unknown on forehand and me be a string with or without AngularJs expression inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate)**.

### $interpolate

> Compiles a string with markup into an interpolation function. This
>   service is used by the HTML $compile service for data binding. See
>   $interpolateProvider for configuring the interpolation markup.

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aqLJT/)**

```
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $interpolate) {

$scope.yourName = "Jim";
$scope.test = "Jack";
$scope.yourTest = $interpolate("{{test}}")($scope);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
<h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1> <!-- works fine, shows 'Jim' -->
<h1>Hello {{yourTest}}!</h1> <!-- will show {{test}}, but I want 'Jack' -->

$scope.yourName = "Jim";
$scope.test = "Jack";
$scope.yourTest = $scope.test;
```

Comment: That will work probably, but unfortunately it should be a string in my case.